# Is it possible to intent multiple times on the same activity but keep history?

Tags: java, android

I am creating a quiz-type of app, where there will be 10 multiple choice questions and each time someone chooses an answer there will be an intent to the same activity but with different questions.

I have solved how to feed the questions each time after the intent but i want to keep history of the previous activities (states?) so if he skipped the question and wants to go back to solve it or if he wants to see what he chose, he has the ability to do that.

I have this code done:

```
intent.putExtra("CorrectIndex", 2);
intent.putExtra("MyChoice", 4);
intent.putExtra("Questions",questions[]);
```

this sends the necessary info to the intent but this is as far as i got.

Is having an array of arrays for the States something like this String[][] States where I keep in the first dimension the activity index and the second dimension the activity info.

(for example [[0,"2","4"][1,"1","5"][2,"4","4"]] where 0 is the activity index, "2" the correctIndex,and "4" my choice) a good solution?

Comment: Perhaps you should be using fragments or composables instead of multiple activities.

Comment: You need to provide more code illustrating how you're launching your Activity. By default, launching the same intent will create a stack with multiple instances of the same activity.